# Unit Tests for BizTalk Maps: How to test a map that depends on the transformation of another map?

Tags: unit-testing, biztalk

I am writing unit tests for BizTalk maps. I have this scenario- **Map1** transforms **input1** to **output1**. **Map2** transforms **output1** to **output2**.

To write unit test for **Map2**, I first need to make sure the first transformation is done and **output1** is in place to be picked up by **Map2** as input.

Should I use ordered tests to make sure first test is run before the second one? I guess this is not a good approach at all considering the fact of second test depending on a file generated by first test.

Or Should I test both maps in one single test method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711652/1724809)?

Or Should I use some sort of setup/teardown for the second test where the first map is executed using TestableMapBase on setup?

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't refactor the maps into a single map for some reason, the single test method is probably your best bet.

You could also write up a test method for the second map that uses "known good" output from the first map; of course, this will have to be updated if Map1 changes, but in that case you'd just want to use your combined test.