# Exclude Test from Parallel Execution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest

I have a unit test written in mstest which fails when run as part of the solution but passes overall, because the underlying code relies on some static state.  This failure is because my tests are being executed in parallel, so other tests clash with this one.

For my testing during development I rely on ncrunch, where I can apply a `[Serial]` attribute which prevents that test only from being run in parallel with other tests.  Is there something similar I can do for the VS and TFS test runners?

I'm not looking for advice on refactoring my tested code not to use a static method - I'm aware this is not ideal, but am looking for a workaround in this case.  I also do not want to disable parallel test execution in general, as there are only one or two which have this requirement.

Comment: do want to run some in parallell and one not in parallell in the same assembly?

Comment: Yes.  Most tests will be in parallel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:
There is a concept of ordered tests https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182630(v=vs.90).aspx

Otherwise some merging of dependent test could, perhaps, be an option for you:
[Controlling execution order of unit tests in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711300/controlling-execution-order-of-unit-tests-in-visual-studio)