# how to give priority to test methods in selenium WebDriver with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I am using Selenium with C# and MS test framework for automation in my project.
I used ordered tests...added some tests in ordered tests and executed that but it's failing because it's unable to open the browser.

I have put my browser opening and URL opening code in one class in  `[TestInitialize]` attribute but not in `[Test Method]` attribute, so I can't add those browser initialization methods in ordered tests.

how to solve this problem and give priority to automation tests in Selenium with C#.

I would like to give priority to different methods from different.cs classes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no fine solution except ordered test.

If you do not like ordered test, you could create a batch file which have the tests run in order with command mstest.exe

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7439a822-3363-4451-81bb-a93257bf2401/how-can-i-execute-all-test-cases-in-specified-priority-order?forum=vststest

OR

Merge your tests into one giant test will work. To make the test method more readable

OR

You can Use Playlist

```
Right click on the test method -> Add to playlist -> New playlist
```

the execution order will be as you add them to the playlist but if you want to change it you have the file

Source :-

[Controlling execution order of unit tests in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711300/controlling-execution-order-of-unit-tests-in-visual-studio)