# TFS test case execution order?

Tags: testing, tfs, automated-tests, order-of-execution

I wonder what determines test case execution order in TFS when running automated test cases, without a "ordered tests" implementation?
See i have 5 automated test cases and they always run in the same order, but one of the test cases does not run in the order i want it to. 
So what determines test case execution order in TFS when running automated test cases without a "ordered tests" implementation?

This is not unit tests. This is coded ui tests associated with TFS test cases.

//Kind regards NB

Comment: If test order is important, why not created ordered tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling execution order of unit tests in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711300/controlling-execution-order-of-unit-tests-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @aridlehoover ordered tests is not an option at this point for some reasons. If you wanna ask more about why just send me a message. 
I just wanna know what TFS default execution order for automated test cases is.
Apprently there is a order since my 5 automated test cases ALWAYS run in the same order.

And no, this is not unit tests. This is coded ui tests associated with TFS test cases.